# Greasemonkey script to remove HTML between specific comments?

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey

In order to block some JavaScript that I don't want to execute when I load a page, I would like to have a Greasemonkey script that deletes everything between two HTML comment tags.  For example:

```
<!-- sub script -->
 Lines containing script elements to be removed
<!-- end sub script -->
```

I have previously tried removing the script elements using a sample script that was suggested to me, but it isn't working as expected.  That script was this:

```
var script = document.querySelectorAll('script[src*="example.com"]');
for (var i = 0, len = script.length; i < len; i++) {
   script[i].parentNode.removeChild(scriptscript[i]);
}
```

Simply put, it doesn't remove the script elements as I had hoped it would. I know that the comment elements are consistent between pages and if I could use those as the markers to begin and end a search and simply delete everything in between, I believe it would solve the problem.

Any guidance would be appreciated. To say I'm new to JavaScript would be an understatement, but I'm a quick learner.

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove a JavaScript script by just removing the `<script>` which included it.

That's because once browser parses the `<script>`, the script runs, and there's no way to undo that.

But on some browsers you can block the script just before it runs, using [`beforescriptexecute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/beforescriptexecute) event:

```
window.addEventListener('beforescriptexecute', function(e) {
    if (~e.target.src.indexOf('example.com')) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}, true);
```

Note your GM script must run before the script you want to block, to be sure, use

```
@run-at document-start
```

Comment: So I've tried this with no success.  Should I be able to use just what you provided, substituting the relevant domain from which I want to block scripts, as the entire body of the GM script?  When I do that, the scripts still load.

Will this catch all instances of scripts from this domain rather than just the first?  There are multiple scripts on the page.

Comment: Yes, no more code is needed to make it work. And it should block all scripts loaded from URLs which contain `'example.com'`. See a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7VeBL/)

Comment: Okay, thanks.  Somehow those scripts are still getting executed.  Maybe they're getting injected after the page loads by another script I haven't blocked?  If necessary I can block the offending domain using AdBlockPlus, which I know works, but I was hoping to use this as a learning exercise.

Comment: @B.Rossow In which browser and version are you trying it? Check `'onbeforescriptexecute' in window` to know if it's supported.

Comment: +1, but for any `<script>` with a `src` attribute, Adblock is the far superior way to block it (faster, easier, less resource intensive, less junk downloaded by the target page).

Comment: @BrockAdams I also think Adblock is useful. But faster and less resource intensive? Last time I tried it, it slowed down Firefox startup by 15 seconds and made it eat 300MB RAM more. I prefer the script above :)

Comment: @Oriol, You're kidding, right?  I haven't noticed *Adblock* slowing startup and Firefox memory use is notoriously hard to pin down, but so what?  AdBlock saves me *minutes* each and every day by blocking gigabytes of crap from ever downloading.  As a bonus, I don't even see all kinds of annoying, blinking, chattering garbage that seems to spam websites.  Also, third-party cruft and ads are now the largest source of hack attempts on websites. Adblock stops a lot of that cold.